# Access query to select rows that are the MAX of one column but unique on another

Tags: ms-access

Lets say I want a table that gives me the 4 columns of data below, but I only want a single row for each unique "ID" using the "Date" column to select only the most recent date for each unique "ID":

```
|--ID--|-Type-|-Code-|--Date--|
|   1  |   A  |  11  |11/07/13|
|   2  |   A  |  11  |11/07/13|
|   2  |   B  |  12  |10/07/13|   <-- don't want this record from ID=2 as
|   3  |   A  |  11  |11/07/13|       there is a more recent date for it
|   4  |   A  |  10  |11/07/13|       than 10/07/2013
|   5  |   A  |  11  |11/07/13|
```

I've tried adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612268/2140244) that seemed to be for a similar question, but I'm getting the following error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an part of an aggregate function

Here's my adapted version of that SQL I was trying to run in Access:

```sql
SELECT ESM.ID, ESM.Type, ESM.Code, ESM.Date
FROM Emp_Stat_Mon As ESM
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT ID, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM Emp_Stat_Mon
    GROUP BY ID
    ) groupedESM ON ESM.ID = groupedESM.ID AND ESM.Date = groupedESM.MaxDate;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This does it:**

```
SELECT  ID, Type, Code, Date
FROM Emp_Stat_Mon t1
WHERE t1.Date = 
    (SELECT Max(t2.Date) 
     FROM Emp_Stat_Mon t2 
     WHERE t2.ID=t1.ID 
     GROUP BY t2.ID)
```

An SQLFiddle with your sample data : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366db/1)

Comment: thanks! works great. I forgot to put this in my question though: how do I filter on "Type" field by say "A" as well? adding `HAVING (((Type)="A"))` brings up an error "HAVING clause without grouping or aggregation".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want ? filtering by Type can simply be done by : [This Sql Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0f5f/2) . is this what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry - I was adding the filter in design view so Access was creating its own code that didn't work. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to get a similar thing working.  I used `DMax()` to get me there, but it essentially does the same thing as Ron's code.

```
SELECT ID, Type, Code, Date
FROM Emp_Stat_Mon As ESM
WHERE ESM.Date = DMax("Date", "Emp_Stat_Mon", "ID=" & ESM.ID);
```

EDIT:

As I was putting this together, I was concerned about performance.  I am expecting my own table to get large, so this method should probably be avoided.  I thought there was good discussion, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841716/534056).  I had trouble getting the second SELECT to work for me, but I think it deserves a second chance!