# Access query to pull records that are max of one record but unique of another

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I tried adapting sql from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592737/access-query-to-select-rows-that-are-the-max-of-one-column-but-unique-on-another) I must be doing something wrong (I know I am because I'm lost when it comes to SQL)  Here's my sample table:  I want the max ID with unique Trailer

```
|--ID--|Trailer|--To--|Load Qty A|Load Type/Config A|
|  1   | A100  |  B6  |     2    |        A1        |
|  2   | A100  |  A4  |     1    |        A1        |  <-Show this
|  3   | B099  |  B2  |     6    |        C23       |  <-Show this
|  4   | A027  |  N10 |     3    |        O1        |
|  5   | J400  |  A4  |     8    |        A1        |  <-Show this
|  6   | A027  |  A4  |     4    |        B24       |  <-Show this
```

I understand this is basically the same structure as the post linked above, but I really cannot get it to work.  I thought that I had it working simply by having everything in the query as "last" except for trailer which I had "group by" but it started outputting incorrect records.

Comment: I figured it out.
I created a query for just ID and trailer, set ID to Max and Trailer to GroupBy.  Then I created another query with the rest of the fields and simply created a relationship between the ID fields.

Comment: If this closes the question for you, please add your comment as answer and accept it

Comment: I had to wait over 8 hours to answer my own question since I'm a new member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
I created a query for just ID and trailer, set ID to Max and Trailer to GroupBy.  Then I created another query with the rest of the fields and simply created a relationship between the ID fields.